# Jenkins configuration with active directory and "userWorkstations"

Tags: jenkins, active-directory, ldap

I am creating a build envirnoment and freshly installed jenkins with ActiveDirectory/LDAP auth.

We will have external users which should not be able to login to our domain computers but they should have access to jenkins/jira/... in order to develop with us (perhaps vpn for accessing some dev backends).

So for these users in active directory I set a dummy host they are able to logon (which means no computer at all). Jira/Confluence and dav_svn have no problem with this but it seems jenkins checks this property and refuses the access.

Can anybody tell me what "host" I have to put in there so that jenkins accepts a logon of these users? Or if I have to set a hidden config value in jenkins?

The users to accept are all in a special developer group. If I could simply pass the name of the group but even this does not help (matrix based): the user cannot login.

Thanks ver much!
Aurel